# Using an iPad Pro and an Apple Pencil as a "tablet"

Tags: macos, ipad

I was wondering if it is possible to use an iPad Pro sort of like a Wacom Tablet (or LiveScribe - but LiveScribe has a delay), where you can use the Apple Pencil to write notes on the iPad, and the notes instantly appear on the Mac's screen with no delay. This would be really useful for my online college assignments because half of the screen would be taken up with the notes I take on the iPad and the other half with the problems and I could easily solve algebraic problems.

I would prefer not to use screen mirroring just so it was easier to save the files on the Mac and interact with the scribbles directly on the Mac (zoom in, rotate, etc)

I would prefer to do it over Lightning cable just to avoid any WiFi delays my school has.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called Astropad that allows this. http://www.macworld.com/article/2885834/first-look-astropad-turns-your-ipad-into-a-graphics-tablet-for-your-mac.html

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.